# Visual Studio does not show me all downloaded Android versions - SDK Manager

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working with Visual Studio developing an app with **Xamarin.Android** but I found a problem that is giving me a lot of headache because it prevents me from downloading the **NuGets** that I need (`Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging`).

The main problem is that I download all the versions of Android from the SDK Manager, but when I want to select `Android 9` (API 28) or `Android 10` as "`Target Android Version`", it shows me all up to Android 8, I mean, no It shows me neither Android 9 nor anything else above.

I have already tried to update, uninstall the packages and reinstall them, and nothing works.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Any advice? 
At least to be able install the NuGet that I need to implement Push notifications in my app?

Comment: Have you checked you are using the latest version of windows 10 ?

Comment: If you are now seeing Xamarin.Android 9+ you are using an outdated version of Xamarin.Android.

Comment: what's your Visual Studio ?if your Visual Studio is low version,you won't be able to target Android to high api  even if they are installed through the SDK manager

Comment: Yes, you're right @LeoZhu-MSFT. That was the problem. Thank you very much. 
You too SushiHangover.